# Random number generators C++ and Python

Tags: python, c++

I have programmed a model in both C++ and Python. This model has a noisy-input component, which I can replace with this C++:

```cpp
double doubleRand() {
    thread_local std::mt19937 generator(std::random_device{}());
    std::normal_distribution<double> distribution(0.0, 1.0);
    return distribution(generator);
}
```

Or this Python:

```py
Inoise = (np.random.normal(0, 1) * knoise * np.sqrt(gNa * A))
IIon = ((iNa + iK + iL) * A) + Inoise  #

# Compute change of voltage
v[i + 1] = (vT + ((-IIon + IStim) / C) * dt)[0]
```

The following is very strange:
If I omit the noisy component (Inoise=0), then both models (C++ as well as Python) give exactly the same result. If I only introduce the noisy component (Istim=0), then both models give results (i.e. natural fluctuations that hardly differ from each other at 1000 runs). However, if I choose Istim=0.000001 and add noise, then the results differ by 30%. How is that possible?

Here is the full code. C++:

```cpp
#include<math.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<random>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<fstream>
#include<omp.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <assert.h>


// parameters
constexpr double v_Rest = -65.0;
constexpr double gNa = 1200.0;
constexpr double gK = 360.0;
constexpr double gL = 3.0;
constexpr double vNa = 115.0;
constexpr double vK = -12.0;
constexpr double vL = 10.6;
constexpr double c = 1.0;
constexpr double knoise = 0.0005;

bool print = false;
bool bisection = false;
bool test = true;

// stepsize PFs
constexpr int steps = 5;

double store[steps];
int prob[steps];
double step[steps];



// time constants
constexpr double t_end = 1.0;
constexpr double delay = 0.1;
constexpr double duration = 0.1;
constexpr double dt = 0.0025;
constexpr int t_steps = t_end/dt;

constexpr int runs = 1000;

double voltage[t_steps];

    double doubleRand() {
        thread_local std::mt19937 engine(std::random_device{}());
        std::normal_distribution<double> distribution(0.0, 1.0);
        return distribution(engine);
    }

    double alphaM(const double v){ return 12.0 * ((2.5 - 0.1 * (v)) / (exp(2.5 - 0.1 * (v)) - 1.0)); }

    double betaM(const double v){ return 12.0 * (4.0 * exp(-(v) / 18.0)); }

    double betaH(const double v){ return 12.0 * (1.0 / (exp(3.0 - 0.1 * (v)) + 1.0)); }

    double alphaH(const double v){ return 12.0 * (0.07 * exp(-(v) / 20.0)); }

    double alphaN(const double v){ return 12.0 * ((1.0 - 0.1 * (v)) / (10.0 * (exp(1.0 - 0.1 * (v)) - 1.0))); }

    double betaN(const double v){ return 12.0 * (0.125 * exp(-(v) / 80.0)); }

    double HH_model(const double I, const double area_factor){

        const double A = 1.0e-8 * area_factor;
        const double C = c*A;

        const double v0 = 0.0;
        const double m0 = alphaM(v0)/(alphaM(v0)+betaM(v0));
        const double h0 = alphaH(v0)/(alphaH(v0)+betaH(v0));
        const double n0 = alphaN(v0)/(alphaN(v0)+betaN(v0));

        int count = 0;

        for(int j=0; j<runs; j++){

            double vT = v0;
            double mT = m0;
            double hT = h0;
            double nT = n0;

            for(int i=0; i<t_steps; i++){

                double IStim = 0.0;
                if ((delay / dt <= (double)i) && ((double)i <= (delay + duration) / dt))
                   IStim = I;

                mT = (mT + dt * alphaM(vT)) / (1.0 + dt * (alphaM(vT) + betaM(vT)));
                hT = (hT + dt * alphaH(vT)) / (1.0 + dt * (alphaH(vT) + betaH(vT)));
                nT = (nT + dt * alphaN(vT)) / (1.0 + dt * (alphaN(vT) + betaN(vT)));

                const double iNa = gNa * pow(mT, 3.0) * hT * (vT - vNa);
                const double iK = gK * pow(nT, 4.0) * (vT - vK);
                const double iL = gL * (vT-vL);
                const double Inoise =  (doubleRand() * knoise * sqrt(gNa * A));
                const double IIon = ((iNa + iK + iL) * A) + Inoise;

                vT += ((-IIon + IStim) / C) * dt;
                voltage[i] = vT;

                if(vT > 60.0) {
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
 return count;
}
    
int main(){
    
     std::cout << HH_model(1.0e-6,1) << std::endl;
    
    }
       
    }
```

Python:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as py
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as optimize
from tqdm import tqdm
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)

# HH parameters
v_Rest = -65    # in mV
gNa = 1200      # in mS/cm^2
gK = 360      # in mS/cm^2
gL = 0.3*10      # in mS/cm^2
vNa = 115      # in mV
vK = -12       # in mV
vL = 10.6      # in mV

#Number of runs

runs = 1000


c = 1         # in uF/cm^2


        
def alphaM(v): return 12 * ((2.5 - 0.1 * (v)) / (np.exp(2.5 - 0.1 * (v)) - 1))
        
        
def betaM(v):  return 12 * (4 * np.exp(-(v) / 18))
        
        
        
def betaH(v): return 12 * (1 / (np.exp(3 - 0.1 * (v)) + 1))
        
        
def alphaH(v): return 12 * (0.07 * np.exp(-(v) / 20))
        
        
def alphaN(v): return 12 * ((1 - 0.1 * (v)) / (10 * (np.exp(1 - 0.1 * (v)) - 1)))
        
        
def betaN(v): return 12 * (0.125 * np.exp(-(v) / 80))
        


def HH_model(I,area_factor):
    
    count = 0
    t_end = 1  # in ms
    delay = 0.1     # in ms
    duration = 0.1    # in ms
    dt = 0.0025   # in ms
    area_factor = area_factor
        
    I = I
    C = c*A    # uF
     
    
    for j in tqdm(range(0, runs), total=runs):
        
        # Introduction of equations and channels
        

        
        # compute the timesteps
        t_steps= t_end/dt+1

        
        # Compute the initial values
        v0 = 0
        m0 = alphaM(v0)/(alphaM(v0)+betaM(v0))
        h0 = alphaH(v0)/(alphaH(v0)+betaH(v0))
        n0 = alphaN(v0)/(alphaN(v0)+betaN(v0))
        
        # Allocate memory for v, m, h, n
        v = np.zeros((int(t_steps), 1))
        m = np.zeros((int(t_steps), 1))
        h = np.zeros((int(t_steps), 1))
        n = np.zeros((int(t_steps), 1))
        
        # Set Initial values
        v[:, 0] = v0
        m[:, 0] = m0
        h[:, 0] = h0
        n[:, 0] = n0
         
        
        ### Noise component
        knoise=  0.0005  #uA/(mS)^1/2
        ###  --------- Step3: SOLVE
        for i in range(0, int(t_steps)-1, 1):
        
        # Get current states
           vT = v[i]
           mT = m[i]
           hT = h[i]
           nT = n[i]
        
        # Stimulus current
           IStim = 0
           if delay / dt <= i <= (delay + duration) / dt:
               IStim = I    # in uA
           else:
               IStim = 0
        
        
        #  Compute change of m, h and n 
               m[i + 1] = (mT + dt * alphaM(vT)) / (1 + dt * (alphaM(vT) + betaM(vT)))
               h[i + 1] = (hT + dt * alphaH(vT)) / (1 + dt * (alphaH(vT) + betaH(vT)))
               n[i + 1] = (nT + dt * alphaN(vT)) / (1 + dt * (alphaN(vT) + betaN(vT)))
        
        
        # Ionic currents
           iNa = gNa * m[i + 1] ** 3. * h[i + 1] * (vT - vNa)    
           iK = gK * n[i + 1] ** 4. * (vT - vK)                     
           iL = gL * (vT-vL)                                           
           Inoise = (np.random.normal(0, 1) * knoise * np.sqrt(gNa * A))
           IIon = ((iNa + iK + iL) * A) + Inoise   # 
        
        # Compute change of voltage
           v[i + 1] = (vT + ((-IIon + IStim) / C) * dt)[0]   # in ((uA / cm ^ 2) / (uF / cm ^ 2)) * ms == mV
        
        
        # adjust the voltage to the resting potential
        v = v + v_Rest
     
        # test if there was a spike
        
        if max(v[:]-v_Rest) > 60:
            count += 1
        
        
              
           
    return count
```

Comment: Individual [`std::random_device`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) instances are not guaranteed to produce different numbers. They often do, but it's not guaranteed: "`std::random_device` may be implemented in terms of an implementation-defined pseudo-random number engine if a non-deterministic source (e.g. a hardware device) is not available to the implementation. In this case each `std::random_device` object may generate the same number sequence."

Comment: @JohnKugelman so I could use static?

Comment: I don't think it's causing your issue. Just a gotcha that you should keep in mind separately.

Comment: You might have a `static std::random_device` that you use for your seed (with protected (mutex) access).

Comment: So both codes provide the same when deterministic, and provide the same when I=0, and only Inoise is added... but when I is not zero and Noise is added, then the results differ

Comment: @JohnKugelman I can't explain this to me... but it has to do something with the stochastic component

Comment: @JohnKugelman is it really possible that it is because of the random number generators? that is, that the difference between c++ and python is so great in the generation of random numbers? but then why do the codes match well at I=0 and only noise?

Comment: Did you try to use numpy.random.MT19937?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've messed up indents in the Python code. These lines

```py
m[i + 1] = (mT + dt * alphaM(vT)) / (1 + dt * (alphaM(vT) + betaM(vT)))
h[i + 1] = (hT + dt * alphaH(vT)) / (1 + dt * (alphaH(vT) + betaH(vT)))
n[i + 1] = (nT + dt * alphaN(vT)) / (1 + dt * (alphaN(vT) + betaN(vT)))
```

do not execute when condition `delay / dt <= i <= (delay + duration) / dt` is True

After indentation is fixed the Python code produces 866, which nearly matches 876 - result of C++ code.